# How to use arduino to run .exe file in a windows computer

Tags: arduino-uno

Is there a way to run .exe file **on a windows computer that connected to arduino**? (I want to create some sort of stream deck, but it will be used for running Google Chrome and other .exe file on a windows computer)

Can someone explain how to run it using arduino uno by taking input from the user?

Comment: how do you normally run  microsoft edge?

Comment: double clicking the shortcut, or using cmd

Comment: don't forget that the subject of your question is about an external device that is connected to a computer ... so `double clicking the shortcut, or using cmd` does not answer the question I asked ... anyway, program the arduino to be one of the external devices that you use to control your computer

Comment: Ah I see, but I only find some tutorials on how to use the arduino as an automated keyboard, is there a way I use it to open microsoft edge without using my arduino as an automated keyboard?

Comment: Maybe use a script (say Powershell) running on the PC. It constantly checks a Serial port for any commands the arduino may send it. The script interprets such commands and initiatives an appropriate action. In your case this would be opening Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try!

Comment: setup keyboard shortcuts in Windows to run the programs. then if you still need it, you can use an Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Micro to send this keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Ah I just figured out that there is Arduino Leonardo, I will try using that one

Comment: @Juraj: I believe your comment would make a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, one way to do this would be to bind a windows shortcut key to do the action you desire and then have the arduino send that as a keystroke.  This would only be possible on devices (like the leonardo) that have native usb device support rather than a serial to usb converter chip.

An alternate (and more secure and reliable) approach would be to create a windows service that looks for the arduino and monitors it and runs actions when the arduino generates specific events.

The easiest way to get events would be to read incoming serial data from the arduino and parse it; this would work on all arduinos.  A more complex approach (only available on arduinos with native usb device support) would be to create a special USB device profile that generated the events, and a corresponding windows service or driver to recognize and use that custom device.

I've done things like this with my own projects, although in linux, not in windows.